# Blowfish code should be equivalent but is not

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

We have a class which wraps BouncyCastle (actually SpongyCastle for Android) Blowfish to encrypt data to stream:

```
public class BlowfishOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
    private final OutputStream os;
    private final PaddedBufferedBlockCipher bufferedCipher;
```

Our original code encrypted a whole byte array before writing to the output stream in a single operation

```
public void write(byte[] raw, int offset, int length) throws IOException
{
    byte[] out = new byte[bufferedCipher.getOutputSize(length)];
    int result = this.bufferedCipher.processBytes(raw, 0, length, out, 0);
    if (result > 0)
    {
        this.os.write(out, 0, result);
    }
}
```

When sending images (ie large amount of data at once) it results in two copies being retained in memory at once.

The following code is meant to be equivalent but is not, and I do not know why. I can verify that data is being sent (sum of `c2` is equivalent to the `length`) but an intermediate process when it is received on our server discards the image before we get to see what arrives. All I know at this stage is that when the initial code is used, the response is received and the included images can be extracted, when the replacement code is used the response is received (and accepted) but images do not appear to be extracted.

```
public void write(byte[] raw, int offset, int length) throws IOException
{
    // write to the output stream as we encrypt, not all at once.
    final byte[] inBuffer = new byte[Constants.ByteBufferSize];
    final byte[] outBuffer = new byte[Constants.ByteBufferSize];
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(raw);
    // read into inBuffer, encrypt into outBuffer and write to output stream
    for (int len; (len = bis.read(inBuffer)) != -1;)
    {
        int c2 = this.bufferedCipher.processBytes(inBuffer, 0, len, outBuffer, 0);
        this.os.write(outBuffer, 0, c2);
    }
}
```

**Note** that the issue is **not** due to a missing call to `doFinal`, as this is called when the stream is closed.

```
public void close() throws IOException
{
    byte[] out = new byte[bufferedCipher.getOutputSize(0)];
    int result = this.bufferedCipher.doFinal(out, 0);
    if (result > 0)
    {
        this.os.write(out, 0, result);
    }
    *nb try/catch omitted*
}
```

Comment: I think I have the solution, where the second algorithm doesn't honour the `length` passed in and instead assumes that the entirety of `raw` is the message. Testing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed, although ironically the issue was not with the images but in previous data, but that data was writing the complete `raw` byte array and not just the range specified. The equivalent code for encrypting the byte array on the fly is:

```
@Override
public void write(byte[] raw, int offset, int length) throws IOException
{
    // write to the stream as we encrypt, not all at once.
    final byte[] inBuffer = new byte[Constants.ByteBufferSize];
    final byte[] outBuffer = new byte[Constants.ByteBufferSize];
    int readStart = offset;
    // read into inBuffer, encrypt into outBuffer and write to output stream
    while(readStart<length)
    {
        int readAmount = Math.min(length-readStart, inBuffer.length);
        System.arraycopy(raw, readStart, inBuffer, 0, readAmount);
        readStart+=readAmount;
        int c2 = this.bufferedCipher.processBytes(inBuffer, 0, readAmount, outBuffer, 0);
        this.os.write(outBuffer, 0, c2);
    }
}
```

Comment: and slightly better is to omit the inBuffer and read from the `raw` starting from the `readStart` and use `ByteBufferSize` rather than `inBuffer.length`. Note that Android likes to work with byte[8x1024] (8k) buffers